# Personalised 'To' field when sending large email list using PHP mail and multiple addresses in the Bcc

Tags: php, email

Im trying to remember a trick i was taught a while back but can not.

Basically, im using PHP mail() in this fashion:

```
$to = "emailAddress1@domain.com";
$subject = "Welcome to BuildSanctuary";
$messageContent = "Thankyou for registering Bla bla bla";
$message = 'SOME HTML EMAIL STUFF including the $messageContent var';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To:' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Accounts<accounts@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: emailAddress1@domain.com,emailAddress2@domain.com,emailAddress3@domain.com,emailAddress4@domain.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I got told a while back that there was a way that you could put your own email in the to field, but when the users receive the emails it looks like they were personally sent the email and the to field shows just their email.

Is this possible? Cant think how.

Thanks.

Comment: with a BCC, not possible.you'd have to send individual emails to each user if you want their name to show up in the To: field.

Comment: You may be thinking of `Apparently-to:`. Some mail servers add this if there's no `To:` line, putting in the name of the local user that the message is being delivered to.